# How to take the results outside the thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

i want to run 2 codes simultaneously in java so i used thread.here i want to get the results from both thread 1 and thread 2 .Please help
Also im not getting thread.getResults
i think its not working
is there any way to get the results

```
    Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
    private Object result;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        takeInfofromDB();
        result = doSomeLongCalculationsWithThatData();
    }

    public Object getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}

Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
    private Object result;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        takeInfofromDB2();
        result = doSomeLongCalculationsWithThatData2();
    }

    public Object getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}

thread1.start();
thread2.start();
thread1.join();
thread2.join();

Object result1 = thread1.getResult();
Object result2 = thread2.getResult();
```

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly the job for a Future.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

Future<Object> future1 = service.submit( ()->{
     takeInfofromDB();
     return doSomeLongCalculationsWithThatData();
} );

Future<Object> future2 = service.submit( ()->{
     takeInfofromDB2();
     return doSomeLongCalculationsWithThatData2();
} );
Object result1 = future1.get();
Object result2 = future2.get();
```

Also, on another note. With java 11 and higher you can use var.

```
var thread1 = new Thread() {
    private Object result;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        takeInfofromDB();
        result = doSomeLongCalculationsWithThatData();
    }

    public Object getResult() {
        return result;
    }

}
```

Then it retains your new methods.

```
thread1.start();
thread1.join();
Object result = thread1.getResult();
```

Comment: Better answer than mine -- deleting mine in favor of this one. 1+

Comment: Wasn't `var` introduced in JDK 10 ? (Nonetheless, up-voted since it allows calling methods of an anonymous inner class.)

Answer (score 0):

`thread1` and `thread2` are instances of `Thread` class, which doesn't have `getResult()` method. You have to create your own non-anonymous classes that extends `Thread`.

```java
public class Db1Thread extends Thread {
    private Object result;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        takeInfofromDB();
        result = doSomeLongCalculationsWithThatData();
    }

    public Object getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

And then

```java
Db1Thread thread1 = new Db1Thread();
thread1.start();
thread1.join();
Object result1 = thread1.getResult();
```

P.S. the better approach is to use `CompletableFuture` from Java 8+. Here is the brief guide https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture

Comment: Look again at the code in the question. It creates an anonymous inner class that extends `Thread` and adds a `getResult()` method.

Comment: @Abra you are correct but those new methods aren't accessible by caller code as long as instance has type `Thread thread1 = ...`. You can't call a method just because it's declared, you also have to have your instance casted to a proper type

Comment: Thank you for expanding on your answer. Perhaps you should consider adding that comment to it so as to make it clear as to why the OP cannot use anonymous inner class. In fact, this line of code in the original question does not compile in my IDE: `thread1.getResult()`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest another simple solution.

```
Object result1;
Object result2;

Thread thread1 = new Thread( () -> {
    takeInfofromDB();
    result1 = doSomeLongCalculationsWithThatData();
});

Thread thread2 = new Thread( () -> {
    takeInfofromDB2();
    result2 = doSomeLongCalculationsWithThatData();
});

thread1.start();
thread2.start();

thread1.join();
thread2.join();
```

Then you don't need additional `getResult()` method. You can just use `result1` and `result2` after calling joins.